# Writing a size() method for a user-defined Stack class (Linked List)

Tags: java

I'm making my own generic stack data structure using a linked list as the backbone to it but I am in need of making a size() method similar to the built in size method for stacks. I'm unsure of the proper way of doing it with a Linked List structure?

```
public class LLStack<T> implements StackInterface {
private class ListNode
{
    private T data;
    private ListNode link;
    public ListNode(T aData, ListNode aLink)
    {
        data = aData;
        link = aLink;
    }
}
private ListNode head;
public LLStack()
{
    head = null;
}
public void push(Object data)
{
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode((T)data, head);
    head = newNode;
}
public T pop()
{
    if(head == null)//Empty stack
        return null;
    T retVal = head.data;
    head = head.link;
    return retVal;
}
public T peek()
{
    if(head == null)
        return null;
    else
        return head.data;
}
public void print()
{
    ListNode temp = head;
    while(temp != null)
    {
        System.out.println(temp.data);
        temp = temp.link;
    }
}
public int size() {

}
```

Comment: Keep a size field. Keep it up to date when the size changes.

Comment: @user2357112 you mean an incrementor/decrementor attached to my push/pop methods?

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the exact same as the print method.

```
public int size()
{
    ListNode temp = head;
    int size = 0;
    while(temp != null)
    {
        size += 1;
        temp = temp.link;
    }
    return size;
}
```

It's more optimal to store a size field that updates with each pop and push, though. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

Keep a size variable in the class:

```
public class LLStack<T> implements StackInterface {
{
    private int size;
....
```

In your push and pop methods, increment / decrement the size:

```
public void push(Object data)
{
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode((T)data, head);
    head = newNode;
    size ++;
}    
public T pop()
{
    if(head == null)//Empty stack
        return null;
    size --;
    T retVal = head.data;
    head = head.link;
    return retVal;
}
```

Then have a get size method:

```
public int getSize()
{
    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways of doing what you want:

1. Count the list by doing an end-to-end traversal every time the method is called. This is going to be slow and I would not recommend it outside an illustrative example. This way you do not need to store the size as a field:

   ```
   public int size() {
       ListNode current = head;
       int count;
       for(count = 0; current != null; count++)
           current = current.link;
       return count;
   }
   ```
2. A much better way would be to just maintain the count as a private field. The `size` method would just be a fast getter:

   ```
   public int size() { return this.count; }
   ```

   You would have to modify all the methods that change the size to change the value of this field as well:

   ```
   public LLStack() {
       this.head = null;
       this.count = 0;
   }

   public void push(T data) {
       ...
       this.count++;
   }

   public T pop() {
       ...
       this.count--;
       return retval;
   }
   ```